# Очень нужна помощь. В каких предложно-падежных формах наблюдаются Энклитики, а в каких - проклитики

Tags: семантика

Очень нужна помощь. В каких предложно-падежных формах наблюдаются Энклитики, а в каких - проклитики.
Века уходят, и уходят люди —
Нет жизни рокового повторенья,
И лишь случайный отблеск озаренья Нетленной красотой всегда пребудет.
В заветный край пусти меня скорей.
Пусть сердце вновь неведомою птицей
Над голубым сиянием морей
На древний и неясный зов стремится.

Comment: Предложите свой вариант решения.

Answer (score 2):

Века /ухо/дят, и/ ухо/дят лю/ди

— Нет жиз/ни ро/ково/го пов/торень/я,

И лишь/ случай/ный от/блеск о/зарень/я

Нетлен/ной кра/сотой /всегда /пребу/дет.

В завет/ный край/ пусти /меня /скорей/.

Пусть серд/це вновь/ неве/домо/ю пти/цей

Над го/лубым/ сия/нием/ морей/

На древ/ний и/ неяс/ный зов /стремит/ся.

Обратите внимание - написано ямбом, с ударением на 2 слог, это подсказка по ударению.

Проклитики:и уходят,и лишь, в заветный, пусть сердце,над голубым, на древний, и неясный.

В данном случае, в поэтическом тексте "нет жизни" тоже проклитик, но это не служебное слово,это сказуемое, просто пропуск ударения, его мы не пишем. Кто-то даже прочитает с двумя ударениями подряд: нЕт жИзни.

Энклитиков нет.

Answer (score 1):

Есть сомнения по поводу "нет жизни".

Логическое ударение, как мне кажется, ставится на слове "нет", тогда "жизни" теряет ударение и становится энклитиком (возможно).

Answer (score 0):

нашел лишь один проклитик 
над голубым ( и все же сомневаюсь)

Comment: Корректируйте Ваш вопрос вместо того, чтобы писать "ответ".